# from WSDL can we generate java files

Tags: java, web-services, spring-ws, wsdl2java

I have a  WSDL file with me and the service is tactfully  not up so i want do a mock service from the WSDL file

Can we generate Java files from WSDL file? i tried wsdl2java  win CXF but it saying ERROR

Fail to create WSDL_definition

```
C:\Users\malnassar\Desktop\cxf3\apache-cxf-3.0.0-milestone1\bin>wsdl2java -impl ContributorSummaryService_1.wsdl

WSDLToJava Error: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: FAIL_TO_CREATE_WSDL_DEFINITION


C:\Users\malnassar\Desktop\cxf3\apache-cxf-3.0.0-milestone1\bin>wsdl2java  ContributorSummaryService_1.wsdl

WSDLToJava Error: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: FAIL_TO_CREATE_WSDL_DEFINITION


C:\Users\malnassar\Desktop\cxf3\apache-cxf-3.0.0-milestone1\bin>wsdl2java  ContributorSummaryService_1.wsdl

WSDLToJava Error: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: FAIL_TO_CREATE_WSDL_DEFINITION


C:\Users\malnassar\Desktop\cxf3\apache-cxf-3.0.0-milestone1\bin>
```

and tried with 
wsdl2java in axis1.6 it it ends up with 
file not found exception

> C:\Users\malnassar\Desktop\axis2-1.6.2\bin>wsdl2java.bat  -uri
>   ContributorSummaryService_1.wsdl  -o c:\WebService\  -uw

logs

Using

> AXIS2_HOME:   C:\Users\malnassar\Desktop\axis2-1.6.2 Using JAVA_HOME: 
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_33 Retrieving document at
>   'ContributorSummaryService_1.wsdl'. Retrieving schema at
>   'ContributorSummaryService_1_2.xsd', relative to
>   'file:/C:/Users/malnassar/Desktop/axis2-1.6.2/bin/ContributorSummaryService_1.wsdl'.
>   log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (org.apache.axis2.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle). log4j:WARN Please
>   initialize the log4j system properly. Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: Error parsing
>   WSDL
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.(CodeGenerationEngine.java:178)
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24) Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at
>   /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema): faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: An
>   error occurred trying to resolve schema referenced at
>   'ContributorSummaryServ ice_1_2.xsd', relative to
>   'file:/C:/Users/malnassar/Desktop/axis2-1.6.2/bin/ContributorSummaryService_1.wsdl'.:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file was not found:
>   file:/C:/Users/malnassar/Desktop
>   /axis2-1.6.2/bin/ContributorSummaryService_1_2.xsd
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseTypes(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.readInTheWSDLFile(CodeGenerationEngine.java:320)
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.(CodeGenerationEngine.java:133)
>           ... 2 more Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file was not found:
>   file:/C:/Users/malnassar/Desktop/axis2-1.6.2/bin/ContributorSummaryService_1_2.xsd
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.util.StringUtils.getContentAsInputStream(Unknown Source)
>           ... 13 more C:\Users\malnassar\Desktop\axis2-1.6.2\bin>

3 . When try to create a project with  SOAPUI  getting below error

> Error loading
>   [file:\C:\Users\kpane\Desktop\ContributorSummaryService.xsd]:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\kpane\Desktop\ContributorSummaryService.xsd (The system
>   cannot find the file specified

Comment: Can you please share your error from the logs when you attempt to execute wsdl2java?  The community won't be able to assist without more information.

Comment: it seems that the file ContirbutorSummaryService_1_2.xsd is not located where it must to be.

Comment: @kapildas - one more request. "WSDLRuntimeException: FAIL_TO_CREATE_WSDL_DEFINITION" is not a lot by itself and I can see why you did not post it initially.  Could you run one more time with "wsdl2java -impl ContributorSummaryService_1.wsdl -verbose" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to mock and play around with the web service, try using soapui.  souapui.org

Mocking web service using SoapUI : http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/mock-services.html

For generating classe  using wsdl, JDK has in built wsimport tool to do that. Give it a shot.

Comment: @ Kumar  i don't want to use  client

Comment: If you want to mock up your webservice, SoapUI is the perfect choice. http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/mock-services.html. Regarding the file not found exception, make sure you have ContributorSummaryService.xsd file in same folder where you have placed your wsdl file. Your web service provider should be able to provide that file.